# Remember toggled state and avoid flicker on page reload without server side code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I've looked around and couldn't find exactly what I was looking for. So I am using cookies to remember toggled state of div whether it's hidden or visible. The issue I am having is that when the page refresh occurs or I go to a different link, there is flicker that happens as the div goes from default state to the state based on the cookie. And I've been tasked to look into if there is a way to **remove to flicker without server side code**.

Here is the html

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta name="charset" content="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <! -- getCookie() and setCookie() are loaded from app.js -->
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <a href="#" class="buttonCollapse" id="btn-close"><span class="arrow">&laquo;</span>  </a>
  <a href="#" class="buttonCollapse-open" id="btn-open"> <span class="arrow">&raquo;</span> </a>
  <div class="container side-nav">
    <h1>SideBar that has to hide on click</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper" class="main">
    <h1>Main Content</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the css

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  margin: 20px 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hideSideNav .side-nav {
  display: none;
}

.hideSideNav #wrapper {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.main {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.buttonCollapse {
  font-size: : 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  z-index: 10000;
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.buttonCollapse-open {
  font-size: : 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 10000;
  display: none;
}

.buttonCollapse:hover,
.buttonCollapse-open:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

span.arrow {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

And finally here are the getCookie() setCookie() and deleteCookie() functions for your reference which are loaded from app.js

```js
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
  document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
    ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toUTCString() : "") +
    ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
    ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
    ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}

function getCookie(name) {
  var dc = document.cookie;
  var prefix = name + "=";
  var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
  if (begin == -1) {
    begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
    if (begin != 0) return null;
  } else {
    begin += 2;
  }
  var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
  if (end == -1) {
    end = dc.length;
  }
  return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}

function deleteCookie(name, path, domain) {
  if (getCookie(name)) {
    document.cookie = name + "=" +
      ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
      ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
      "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT";
  }
}
```

And here is the my JS. I load this in a script tag immidately after the body tag

```js
if (localStorage.getItem('State')) {
  document.body.classList.add('hideSideNav');
} else {
  document.body.classList.remove('hideSideNav');
}
```

And here is the rest of the code

```js
var btnOpen = "btn-open";
var btnClose = "btn-close";

// Determines which button to show when a page is loaded 
function showElement(elemid) {
  if (elemid != null) {
    document.getElementById(elemid).style.display = "inline-block";
    if (elemid == btnClose) {
      document.getElementById(btnOpen).style.display = "none";
      document.body.classList.remove('hideSideNav');
      [0].classList.remove('hideSideNav');
    } else if (elemid == btnOpen) {
      document.getElementById(btnClose).style.display = "none";
      document.body.classList.add('hideSideNav');
    }
  }
}


// check the state of the cookie and if no cookie is set then set it to visible state 

function checkCookie() {
  var cookieName = getCookie("State");
  var getStatus = (localStorage.getItem('State')) ? localStorage.getItem('State') : getCookie('State');
  if (cookieName != null) {
    showElement(getStatus);
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  checkCookie();
}
var doc = document;
var openBtn = doc.getElementById('btn-open');
var closeBtn = doc.getElementById('btn-close');

// when you click on the button to hide the side-nav
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.classList.add('hideSideNav');
  closeBtn.style.display = "none";
  openBtn.style.display = "inline-block";
  setCookie("State", "btn-open");
  localStorage.setItem('State', 'btn-open');
});

// when you click on the button to show the side-nav
openBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.classList.remove('hideSideNav');
  openBtn.style.display = "none";
  closeBtn.style.display = "inline-block";
  deleteCookie('State');
  localStorage.removeItem('State');
});
```

Comment: _“I load this in a script tag immidately after the body tag”_ - try putting it into the HEAD, and set the class on the HTML element (`document.documentElement`) instead of BODY.

Comment: Because *Javascript*...?

Comment: @CBroe thanks it worked!

Comment: OK, cool - added it as an answer, feel free to accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I load this in a script tag immidately after the body tag

At that point, the browser has likely already started to create the DOM/CSSOM, and to render the content.

Try putting the script into the HEAD, and set the class on the HTML element (`document.documentElement`) instead of BODY.